# Sqoop Import Split by Column Data type

Tags: hive, sqoop

Should the datatype of Split by column in sqoop import always be a number datatype (integer, bignint, numeric)? Can't it be a string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can split on any non numeric datatype.

***But this is not recommended.***

### WHY?

For splitting data Sqoop fires

```
SELECT MIN(col1), MAX(col2) FROM TABLE
```

then divide it as per you number of mappers.

**Now take an example of integer as `--split-by` column**

Table has some `id` column having value 1 to 100 and you using 4 mappers (`-m 4` in your sqoop command)

Sqoop get MIN and MAX value using:

```
SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM TABLE
```

OUTPUT:

1,100

Splitting on integer is easy. You will make 4 parts:

- 1-25
- 25-50
- 51-75
- 76-100

**Now string as `--split-by` column**

Table has some `name` column having value "dev" to "sam" and you using 4 mappers (`-m 4` in your sqoop command)

Sqoop get MIN and MAX value using:

```
SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM TABLE
```

OUTPUT:

dev,sam

Now how will it be divided in 4 parts. As per sqoop [docs](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/7c1754270ff21f533088b946c873321f890da791/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/mapreduce/db/TextSplitter.java#L47),

```
/**
   * This method needs to determine the splits between two user-provided
   * strings.  In the case where the user's strings are 'A' and 'Z', this is
   * not hard; we could create two splits from ['A', 'M') and ['M', 'Z'], 26
   * splits for strings beginning with each letter, etc.
   *
   * If a user has provided us with the strings "Ham" and "Haze", however, we
   * need to create splits that differ in the third letter.
   *
   * The algorithm used is as follows:
   * Since there are 2**16 unicode characters, we interpret characters as
   * digits in base 65536. Given a string 's' containing characters s_0, s_1
   * .. s_n, we interpret the string as the number: 0.s_0 s_1 s_2.. s_n in
   * base 65536. Having mapped the low and high strings into floating-point
   * values, we then use the BigDecimalSplitter to establish the even split
   * points, then map the resulting floating point values back into strings.
   */
```

And you will see the warning in the code:

```
LOG.warn("Generating splits for a textual index column.");
LOG.warn("If your database sorts in a case-insensitive order, "
    + "this may result in a partial import or duplicate records.");
LOG.warn("You are strongly encouraged to choose an integral split column.");
```

In case of Integer example, all the mappers will get balanced load *(all will fetch 25 records from RDBMS)*.

In case of string, there is less probability that data is sorted. So, it's difficult to give similar loads to all the mappers.

---

In a nutshell, Go for integer column as `--split-by` column.

Comment: Is there a way i can see the generated splits ? I think verbose may work.

Comment: @IndranilGayen  Yes on adding `verbose`  you will get range queries used fir creating splits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can do but it is **not recommended** due to performance issue. since we know SQOOP runs boundary query "**select min(pk/split-by column), max(pk/split-by column) from table where condition**" to calculate the split size for the mappers.
split-size = (max - min)/no of mappers

Lets say there is table called employee.

```
id      name  age
  1       baba  20
  2       kishor 30
  3       jay    40
  ..........
  10001   pk    60
```

Senario 1 :

**Performing split-by on id column**

In this case SQOOP will fire boundary query select min(id),max(id) from employee to compute the split size.

```
min = 1
max = 100001

default no of mapper = 4

split-size = (10001-1)/4 = 25000

so each mapper will process 25000 lines of record.
mapper 1:  1 - 25000
mapper 2:  25001-50000
mapper 3:  50001-75000
mapper 4:  75001-100000
```

so its very easy for SQOOP to split the records if we have integral column.

Scenario 2:

**Performing split-by on name column**

In this case SQOOP will fire "select min(name),max(name) from employee" to compute split size.

```
min = baba, max= pk
```

SQOOP wont able to compute split size easily because min and max have text values((min-max)/no of mappers) so it will run TextSplitter class to perform split, which will create extra overhead and may impact the performance.

Note : We need to pass extra argument -D **org.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter= true** to use TextSplitter class.

Answer (score -2):

No, it must be numeric because according to the specs: "By default , sqoop will use query select min(), max() from  to find out boundaries for creating splits." The alternative is to use --boundary-query which also requires numeric columns. Otherwise , the Sqoop job will fail. If you don't have such a column in your table the only workaround is to use only 1 mapper: "-m 1".

Comment: I like dev ツ's answer, which gives details about using strings for splitting.