# Sqoop import split by column choice

Tags: sqoop

All,

When there is no primary key on the source table, and we need to do manual selection for the key how to make choice for split-by key, :

1) is it supposed to be numeric?  or varchar is fine too?
2) can it have nulls
3)  I suppose distribution of values for the column should be as even as possible, but will it matter how many maps I am choosing (--num-map ## )?
or any other criteria to pay attention to?

thanks 
Abhijeet

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37389134/2700344

Comment: Earlier I wrote similar answer. Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40038796/3929393