# Sqoop number of mappers in free-form query import

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

To import the following subset of data from MySQL in Sqoop:

```
mysql> select category_name, count(*) from categories group by category_name having count(*)>1;
```

[image]

I executed the following query :

> sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db
>   --username root --password cloudera --query 'select category_name,count(*) from categories group by category_name having
>   count(*)>1 AND $CONDITIONS' --target-dir /user/cloudera/talli
>   --split-by category_name;

I get the output as:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera/talli

Found 7 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera          0 2018-03-29 13:40 /user/cloudera/talli/_SUCCESS

-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera          0 2018-03-29 13:40 /user/cloudera/talli/part-m-00000

-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera         14 2018-03-29 13:40 /user/cloudera/talli/part-m-00001

-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera          0 2018-03-29 13:40 /user/cloudera/talli/part-m-00002

-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera          0 2018-03-29 13:40 /user/cloudera/talli/part-m-00003

-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera          0 2018-03-29 13:40 /user/cloudera/talli/part-m-00004

-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera         14 2018-03-29 13:40 /user/cloudera/talli/part-m-00005
```

i.e. I could see **6 mapper files.**

Can anybody explain why that is so when the default number of mappers is 4(and when I have not provided any number using -m explicitly)?

Comment: Might be due to splitting on string column. Check my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40038796/3929393), it may help.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I checked your other answer. So, what I surmise out of it, is that though the default no. of mappers is 4, there might be multiple mappers in certain cases, like if split-by <string col>. However, i still could not understand like why the split for the string column here(category_name) could not be done into 4 units.

Comment: can you try this query again by adding `--verbose` (to see extended logs). Range queries used by sqoop should be logged. We can get more information from it.