# sqoop use split by char or string?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, sqoop

I have many tables in Oracle and Sybase DB and it also is big size tables.

Table's pk(primary key) is `char` and multi-column combination.

How do I make Sqoop script? Do I use `'--split by char or string'`?

I just know is't evenly distribute mapper and duplicates.

How do I do?

Comment: Somewhat similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032752/sqoop-import-split-by-column-data-type

Comment: thandk you recommend it . i know it is possible but is is'nt recommend. i just know different way how to handle this kind of issue.